# Wordpress and wp_usermeta PIVOT results

Tags: mysql, wordpress, pivot-table

I am trying to build a report based on user access to the platform.
All user are registered users and they come from different divisions.
All this is stored in the database under the wp_usermeta table.

For example I want the totals of all the users that logged in the month of december of 2020 from HR division. This is what I came with looking at examples from the web:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN meta_value = "HR Division" THEN meta_value END) AS school, 
    (CASE WHEN meta_key = "last-login" AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(meta_value)) = 2020 AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(meta_value)) = 12 THEN meta_value END) AS logins
    (COUNT(user_id)) as totals, 
FROM 
    wp_usermeta
GROUP BY school
```

but gives me the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(COUNT(user_id)) as totals, 
FROM 
    wp_usermeta
GROUP BY school' at line 4
```

I really don't know where to go from here.
Any Ideas?

Comment: You forgot to add a comma (`,`) after `... AS logins`

Comment: True. Didn't realized that.

Answer (score 1):

After looking into more tutorials and browsing for answers here the fila query:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS result FROM (
      SELECT
        wp_users.ID,
        m1.meta_value as department,
        m2.meta_value as login
      FROM
        wp_users
        LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_usermeta AS m1 ON wp_users.ID = m1.user_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_usermeta AS m2 ON wp_users.ID = m2.user_id
      WHERE
        m1.meta_key = "department" AND
        m2.meta_key = "last-login" AND
        m1.meta_value = "HR Department" AND
        YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(m2.meta_value)) = 2020 AND
        MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(m2.meta_value)) = 12

    ) AS mainquery
```

The Query inside parenthesis will list the users ID, the department and the last time the user logged in. The mainquery will return the COUNT of the records.

It's here for all who needed it!!!